# How to change the display of div inside iframe based on parent window title using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have this parent page with title Criatweb,
and an iframe page inside it,
I want to change the display of a div inside the iframe page, but to change only when it's title is Criatweb.
I tried this in the iframe page but didn't have success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.parent.document.title == 'Criatweb')
{document.getElementById('customizarsite').style.display = 'none';}    
</script>
```

Comment: And the error in the console says....

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: so you don't have an element with the ID `customizarsite` in your iframe.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Place it below the 'customizarsite' div or execute it 'onload'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means you are calling it before the element is loaded on the page!

It is like walking through a door before opening it. Not going to happen unless you are a ghost.

You need to call it onload or onready or after the element.

```
<div id="customizarsite">Put the script after me</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.parent.document.title == 'Criatweb') {    
        document.getElementById('customizarsite').style.display = 'none';
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: You sir nailed it! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

use [jQuery hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (window.parent.document.title == 'Criatweb')
 {
    $("#customizarsite").hide();
 }    
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery is not the solution, It will not fix the issue either.